# Can we stop Twilio Outbound Call auto dialing process if rejected by mobile phone?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I am facing an issue that whenever I place an outbound call from Twilio to any mobile phone. And if that call is rejected by mobile phone, then Twilio auto dialed the another call for same mobile number. It does not happen all the time, but rarely. How can we stop that? Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance

I don't know How to stop that auto dialed call.

This is how I am calling to the mobile phone from Twilio.

```cs
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
var call = CallResource.Create(
    url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"),
    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(details.phonenumber),
    from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("my phone number"),
    timeLimit: Int32.Parse(details.callduration)
);
```

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly? Twilio is dialing a second time after the first dial is rejected?
Can you share how you are making the outbound call?

Comment: Yes Sure @Swimburger. I have edited my question with full details

Comment: This is very strange and should not happen. Your code looks fine. I wonder if there's something outside the code you're sharing that's causing some weird bug. I recommend going to the Twilio console, click Monitor on the left nav > Logs > Calls. There you can find your calls and their details. You may find some helpful information there.

Comment: After that, I'd reach out to Twilio support and ask them if they see anything odd happening in your account.